# Accessing specific data from csv file and show on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Having some problems accessing specific data from a csv file. Currently I can see all data in the console but when I try to show a specific data getting undefined. For example in my console I get all data and I want to extract the subtitles and show it on the html in a class score-text.

My console looks like this:

```
subtitle 1,
name1,65%
name2,65%
name3,65%
name4,65%
total,70%
,
subtitle 2,
name1,65%
name2,65%
name3,65%
name4,65%
total,30%
,
subtitle 3,
name1,65%
name2,65%
name3,65%
name4,65%
total,60%
,
subtitle 4,
name1,65%
name2,65%
name3,65%
name4,65%
total,50%
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.csv',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        var rows = data.split(/\n/);
        for (var rowIndex in rows)
        {

            var columns = rows[rowIndex].split(/,/);
            for (var colIndex in columns)
            {
                var colValue = columns[colIndex].trim();

                console.log(colValue);
            }           
        }

        $(".score-text").each(function( index, value ) { 
          value.innerHTML = result[columns[2]] = rows[2];
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: maybe its worth checking libraries like http://papaparse.com/. Can make your life easier

Comment: You are referencing `columns` out of scope.  That's why it's undefined.

Comment: So how do I access the specific data? for each is the correct function to use?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try putting the insertion part into the loop?

```
        var columns = rows[rowIndex].split(/,/);
        for (var colIndex in columns)
        {
        var colValue = columns[colIndex].trim();

        console.log(colValue);

        $(".score-text").append(colValue);

        }
```